# Turning shared_ptr<T> to reference

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

What is a good practice to return `T&` reference when storing `shared_ptr<T>`?

 
Example Scenario:
I store  `std::shared_ptr<Point> lastLocation;`
and have a signature:
`Point& getlastPosition();`
I thought to make something like:

```
Point& MyClass::getLastLocation(){
    return *lastLocation.get()
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, possibly with some code, what you want to do?  `*pointer_name` gives you a reference to what the pointer points to.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to return a reference when you store a pointer? And what do you return if your pointer doesn't have a valid `Point` (e.g.: is a null pointer)?

Comment: I've put an example @NathanOliver

Comment: @UnholySheep I have to implement task for school and I get a bonus if I don't use raw allocations, so I want to store everything using smart pointers or by value, that said I have functions with signatures predfined

Comment: "Why exactly do you want to return a reference when you store a pointer?" why do you ask such question? Function signature is a public interface, how data is stored is internal implementation, one does not have to reflect another at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work as-is. The call to `get()` is redundant though: The shared pointer itself can be dereferenced as-is using the dereference operator, yielding the reference you want. So it's sufficient to simply write

```
Point& MyClass::getLastLocation(){
    return *lastLocation;
}
```

Bear in mind that `Point`, unless its name is not descriptive of what it is, probably doesn't need to be stored in dynamic memory in the first place. Examine your code design and consider whether you need a pointer of any kind in the first place.

Comment: I won't say there are no reasons to do this but think very carefully about what you are doing.  You are returning a reference to an object owned by a `shared_ptr` without incrementing the reference count.  If the shared pointer's reference count reaches zero the object will be deallocated and the reference you returned will now point to an invalid object.

Comment: @FrankBoyne when I return shared_ptr the ref count increases

Comment: @DanielMeltzer That's not my experience in Visual Studio 2017 C++ or GDB.  Here's a [test program in GDB](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ0D5vX1X).  Run the program and you'll get a segmentation fault after the ~Target() destructor is called by the shared pointer reaching reference count = 0.  Fork the code and run it in the debugger and you'll see that the shared pointer has a strong reference count of 1 even after the reference has been returned.

Comment: cpp.sh/3tgj5 is an exempale

Comment: @DanielMeltzer The penny drops.  Note that in [your example](http://www.cpp.sh/3tgj5) the method `getPrice` returns a result of type `std::shared_ptr<int>` not `T&` as your original question asked for (and as the answer you have accepted does).  It would help future readers if you edited your original question to show you want a result of `shared_ptr<Point>` rather than `Point &`.  It would also help if @xirema updated their answer to reflect that change.